# Is there anyway I add some logic to default exception thrower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, irb

Is there anyway I can override default exception thrower method in ruby ?

Something like, I want to puts "Hello world" in every time error occurs in my application.

**By default**

```
2.2.2 :001 > sure_error
NameError: undefined local variable or method `sure_error' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
    from /home/gas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.2.2 :002 >
```

**What I want**

```
2.2.2 :001 > sure_error
Hello World
NameError: undefined local variable or method `sure_error' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
    from /home/gas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.2.2 :002 >
```

I don't want to override raise method and put 'begin, rescue, raise' to all methods in my whole application, because it is so big right now.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to puts some information to log to make my team debug it more easier when we see an exception.

Comment: There are tools and libraries for that. For example https://bugsnag.com/.